# Function call inside mode hook has no effect but manual execution of function from buffer works

Tags: latex, auctex, font-lock

I use `AucTeX` as my latex major mode. I have been trying to setup the minor mode `latex-pretty-symbols` which is available from melpa. I did:

```
;; Install from package-list-packages
(require 'latex-pretty-symbols)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  (lambda () (message "Show that my code ran") (latex-unicode-simplified)))
```

What's supposed to happen is that font-lock should render  `\alpha = 1` as `α = 1` in a latex buffer.

Unfortunately, this doesn't happen in AucTex. Instead I have to either interactively call `latex-unicode-simplified` or manually evaluate <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(latex-unicode-simplified)` from the buffer.

Is there a way to programmatically send keystrokes after a mode is loaded? Is there some other way to tell auctex to do what I want ? I have been trying to solve this for 2.5 hours now so any help is welcome.

**NB 1:** This problem only happens when I use auctex. When I deleted auctex and 
did `(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'latex-unicode-simplified)` then the problem got resolved. But I can't stop using AucTex.

**NB 2:** This problem is not resolved through file local variables, I tried to put a `% eval: (latex-unicode-simplified)` but that did not work

**NB 3:** [The package author is using bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mortiferus/latex-pretty-symbols.el), with issues disabled.

Comment: Incidentally, `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'prettify-symbols-mode)` should also do the trick if you use Emacs≥25.

Comment: Regarding NB 3, bitbucket does have issue trackers, but repository managers can disable them.  This is the case for that particular repository.

Comment: @Stefan : It seems that to actually make good use of `prettify-symbols-mode` I would have to write the prettification rules myself. Is there some code with those rules already written? I can understand that `latex-pretty-symbols` is basically doing that.

Comment: Yes, Emacs≥25 has such rules.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. The sharp-quote (`#'`) is used only before functions, not all symbols.
2. For easy debug and addition/removal of functions to hooks, it's better to first define a function and then add that to the hook.
3. Bare `lambda`s should not be quoted.

```el
(require 'latex-pretty-symbols)

(defun my/LaTeX-mode-stuff ()
  (message "Show that my code ran")
  (latex-unicode-simplified))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my/LaTeX-mode-stuff)
```